# Run android app with locatioin updates always

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile, service

I am fresh new in android development and I have encountered a problem. My req is to build an app that after the login process the user should close the app so it will run at the background. The app purpose is to receive a location updates (real-time) and Activity Transition (Running, Walking, IN_VEHICLE - that the one that is more important) and do some logic if the user is in some location then send to some backend server http request to write some data in the DB.

The location updates are in foreground service with notification and correspond permissions as well as Activity Recognition.

**My Problem:**
After that I put the phone for a few hours (until 1 day) and I don't see any new recorded in my db though they need to be some new once. I don't know where to point my problem so I have few guess:

1. Location foreground service is stop working.
2. Location provider is not provide me the location (fusedLocation btw).
3. activity recognition foreground service is not working.
4. phone enter into a doze mode and not sending the request or close the foreground services.

**What I want any way:** I'll be more then happy if someone can give me point to look at include how can I debug my problem. Or any solution that I can run my app always in the background without user interaction.

**I have tried**: read on WorkManager that is not provide me Updates regularly, make my app in Doze mode whitelist- did not solve the problem.

Thanks for everyone :)

**Edit:**
If the OS kills my app's foreground, is t make scene to create WorkManager that every 15 min will create some http request (like ping) and start foreground services that might killed?

Comment: First thing I would try is to set the limit for allowed background processes to "no background process" in the android developer settings. This kills your activity as soon as you open a new one and lets you easier debug how your foreground process works when your activities stopped working.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have tried and as expected the foreground service has been killed with the app.